# Run two c programs simultaneously in Xcode

Tags: c, xcode, build, linker

I have two c files, client.c and server.c. From the command line, I can just compile both, open two terminal tabs, and run each in one, so that I can see how they interact with each other. Each one of them consists only of one function, main, which runs forever until terminated manually.

I'd like to speed up the process by running these from Xcode. I created a new project called 'exercise' which contains these two files as well as a number of text and other files. However, when I click on run, it gives me a linker error saying the symbol _main is duplicate. How can I specify to XCode which c file I want to run, or better yet, tell it to run both files independently when I click run?

Comment: You'll want to open two Xcode projects.

Comment: Uh oh, I was hoping that wouldn't be the solution. Is it possible to / is there any advantage to using two 'products' or 'targets' instead?

Comment: I don't know about xcode, but in some IDE's I've worked with, you can give s string to "this is what/how I want to execute my program when I click `Run`" - in which case you may give that a shell-script "run-myprogA-and-myprogB" rather than "myprogA" or "myprogB". Since I don't actually know xcode, I can't say if this is possible or not.